# Getting java.lang.ClassNotFoundException when using package

Tags: java, java-11, javacompiler, java-package

I have a java file `ComPac.java` with the below code:

```
package com;
public class ComPac{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello World");
    }
}
```

The file is located at the path : `/home/ec2-user/java_c`

To compile this file, I ran `javac Compac.java`, and the class file was generated.

[image]

Now its turn to run the class file.

So I did `java ComPac`(screenshot below)

[image: java ComPac]

Understandably, I got the error `Error: Could not find or load main class ComPac. Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/ComPac (wrong name: ComPac).`
This I am assuming is because the java file has the package `com` declared in it.

So instead I tried, `java com.ComPac` and expected it to work(screenshot below).

[image: java com.ComPac]

But I got the error: `Error: Could not find or load main class com.ComPac. Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.ComPac`.

So how do I run this? and what exactly is the logic for running when it comes to packages in java?

Java used- `openjdk version "11.0.8" 2020-07-14 LTS(AWS Corretto)`

OS used- `Amazon Linux 2`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

put the class in a folder called "com"

in a bash shell it's then:

```
$ java com/ComPac
```

(from the folder containing "com", not inside of "com")

Comment: can u elaborate on the logic for this ? does the os folder structure necessarily always need to match the package of the java file? or maybe if thats too much can u point to any  resource where i can learn more about this ? new to java here

Comment: @Zeus for the standard class loading, the folder structure should match the packages. Note that `javac` creates this structure automatically when you use the `-d` option to specify a target directory. That target directory will be the directory you should specify as class path (or a part of it) using the `-cp` option when launching your Java application.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using `Java 11` then you don't need to first compile java file and then run the `class` file. You can directly run the java file using just

`java .\test.java`

> test.java

```
package com;

public class test{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello World");
    }
}
```

command:

`java .\test.java`

Output:

```
Hello World
```

Answer (score 2):

The correct way of doing it as follows:

```
javac -d . ComPac.java
```

The switch `-d .` asks the compiler to place generated class files at the current directory as `.` stands for the current directory. Learn more about the switches by simply using the command `javac`

Now, if you use the command `ls` in Mac/Unix or `dir` in Windows, you will see a directory, `com` has been created and `ComPac.class` has been placed inside this directory. In order to execute the class, you can now use the following command:

```
java com.ComPac
```