# Run a Java Class with Command-Line

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have 4 Java-Data:

```
Common.java
Constants.java
KeywordsEditor.java
ExecutionEngine.java (There is here a Main-Method)
```

I have successful compiled in Command-Line with this Command from Project-Directory (C:\ProjectDemo\src\main\java\ValueInput)

```
javac -cp "C:\Users\ABC\selenium-java-2.48.2\selenium-2.48.2\selenium-java-2.48.2.jar;selenium-server-standalone-3.141.59.j‌​ar" *.java
```

I got 4 Data .class in the same Directory. Now i want to run them with this code:

```
java -cp "C:\Users\ABC\selenium-java-2.48.2\selenium-2.48.2\selenium-java-2.48.2.jar;selenium-server-standalone-3.141.59.j‌​ar" ExecutionEngine
```

But i got Error:

````
Error: ExecutionEngine main class could not be found or loaded 

``` 
I've tried with some same code else:
```
java -cp "C:\Users\ABC\selenium-java-2.48.2\selenium-2.48.2\selenium-java-2.48.2.jar;libs\*;selenium-server-standalone-3.141.59.j‌​ar" ExecutionEngine 

java -cp "C:\Users\ABC\selenium-java-2.48.2\selenium-2.48.2\selenium-java-2.48.2.jar;libs/*;selenium-server-standalone-3.141.59.j‌​ar" ExecutionEngine 
```

And some more, but they don't work. Can somebody help me?
````

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Update

From your comment, I learnt that you have `package ValueInput;` mentioned in `ExecutionEngine.java`. Therefore, you should use the switch `-d` when compiling:

```
javac -d . -cp "C:\Users\ABC\selenium-java-2.48.2\selenium-2.48.2\selenium-java-2.48.2.jar;selenium-server-standalone-3.141.59.j‌​ar" *.java
```

The option `-d .` asks the compiler to place the generated class files at the current directory. Now, if you use the command `ls` in Mac/Unix or `dir` in Windows, you will see a directory, `ValueInput` has been created and all the `.class` files have been placed inside this directory. Learn more about the switches by simply using the command `javac`

In order to execute `ExecutionEngine.class`, you can now use the following command:

```
java -cp ".;C:\Users\ABC\selenium-java-2.48.2\selenium-2.48.2\selenium-java-2.48.2.jar;selenium-server-standalone-3.141.59.j‌​ar" ValueInput.ExecutionEngine
```

You can also check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63319381/10819573) for a similar solution.

**Side note:** You should follow the [Java naming conventions](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/codeconventions-namingconventions.html). As per the convention, the name of the package should be something like `value.input`.

## Original answer

The root cause of the problem is using only jars with `-cp`. You missed realizing that your `ExecutionEngine.class` is not in the jars; rather it is at the current directory which is denoted by a dot (`.`) which you missed to include in the classpath.

Thus, the correct command will be:

```
java -cp ".;C:\Users\ABC\selenium-java-2.48.2\selenium-2.48.2\selenium-java-2.48.2.jar;selenium-server-standalone-3.141.59.j‌​ar" ExecutionEngine
```

It doesn't matter where you put `.` i.e. the current directory e.g. the following will also work for you:

```
java -cp "C:\Users\ABC\selenium-java-2.48.2\selenium-2.48.2\selenium-java-2.48.2.jar;selenium-server-standalone-3.141.59.j‌​ar;." ExecutionEngine
```

**Note for Mac:**

The separator used for this purpose in Mac is `:` instead of `;` e.g.

```
javac -cp mysql-connector-java-5.1.49.jar MysqlDemo.java
java -cp mysql-connector-java-5.1.49.jar:. MysqlDemo
```

**Note for Java-11 onwards:**
[Java-11 allows launching Single-File Source-Code programs](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/330) without compiling e.g.

```
java -cp mysql-connector-java-5.1.49.jar MysqlDemo.java
```

You can learn more about it from [this article](https://www.infoq.com/articles/single-file-execution-java11/).

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your answer, i have tried both solutions, but it still not work. I'm working with Windows, not with Linux

Comment: Try removing the double-quotes.

Comment: @MusterTester - Does `ExecutionEngine.java` have `package ...` line in the beginning?

Comment: Yes, 4 java-Data are in package ValueInput (C:\ProjectDemo\src\main\java\ValueInput). After compiled i'v got 8 data (four .java and 4 .class in the same Directory)

Comment: It doesn't work. I'm also in this directory: C:\ProjectDemo\src\main\java\ValueInput>java -cp ".;C:\Links\H_MA\selenium-java-2.48.2\selenium-2.48.2\selenium-java-2.48.2.jar;selenium-server-standalone-3.141.59.jar" ValueInput/ExecutionEngine

Comment: @MusterTester - I've added an update to my answer. Feel free to comment in case it doesn't work.

Comment: Thank you for your response. This Problem make me sick. I'v tried all possibilities, but it still not work, haizzzzzzz :(

Comment: I need to check your java files. If you can send me the files, I can look into it and help you solve the problem.

Comment: Hi, Don't worry more about that. It was a spelling mistake, my bad !!! This work now with your solution: java -cp ".;C:\Users\ABC\selenium-java-2.48.2\selenium-2.48.2\selenium-java-2.48.2.jar;selenium-server-standalone-3.141.59.j‌​ar" ExecutionEngine. Many thanks :)